# Как правильно прописать путь к серверу для отправки сокета

Tags: javascript, php, сокет, chat, vds

Я делаю чат на сайте, и для этого у меня есть сервер или дежурный скрипт, который принимает сообщения и отправляет сообщения клиенту.

Сайт размещён на VDS-сервере. в Cron'е сервера добавлена задача:

```
php /home/admin/web/cy84161.tw1.ru/public_html/messages/server.php
```

Первоначально на клиенте я создаю сокет:

```
var socket = new WebSocket("ws://cy84161.tw1.ru:8070/messages/server.php");
```

Но при этом сокет выдаёт ошибку, связанную с отсутствием соединения. Подскажите, как правильно прописать путь до дежурного файла при создании сокета, и что здесь не так. Ниже приведу полностью тексты скриптов, ответственных за обмен сообщениями.

chat.js

```
function message(text) {
    var a = $('#chat-result');
    a.append(text);
    a.animate({scrollTop: a.prop("scrollHeight")},'slow');
}

function writeMessage(message) {
    //Сохранение сообщений в БД, здесь всё работает без ошибок
    var http = false;
    if(navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") http = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    else http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.abort();
    http.open("POST", "talking_write.php", true);
    http.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    http.send(
        "sender=" + message.chat_sender +
        "&message=" + message.chat_message);
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var socket = new WebSocket("ws://cy84161.tw1.ru:8070/messages/server.php");
    socket.onopen = function() {
        message("<div>Соединение установлено</div>");
    };
    socket.onerror = function(error) {
        message("<div>Ошибка при соединении" + (error.message ? error.message : "") + "</div>");
    };
    socket.onclose = function() {
        message("<div>Соединение закрыто</div>")
    };
    socket.onmessage = function(event) {
        var data = JSON.parse(event.data);
        switch (data.type) {
            case "connected":
                message('<div>Присоединение с IP-адреса: ' + data.message + '</div>');
                break;
            case "disconnected":
                message('<div>Отсоединение IP-адреса: ' + data.message + '</div>');
                break;
            case "chat-box":
                message('<div><span style = "color: red">' + data.sender + ': </span>' + data.message + '</div>');
                break;
        }
    };

    $("#chat").on('submit', function() {
        var message = {
            chat_sender: $("#chat-sender").val(),
            chat_message: $("#chat-message").val(),
        };
        writeMessage(message);
        socket.send(JSON.stringify(message));
        return false;
    });
});
```

server.php

```
<?php
    require_once("chat.php");

    define("PORT", "8070");
    $chat = new Chat();
    $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
    socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);
    socket_bind($socket, 0, PORT);
    socket_listen($socket);

    $clentSocketarray = array($socket);

    while(true) {
        $newSocketArray = $clentSocketarray;
        $nullA = array();
        socket_select($newSocketArray, $nullA, $nullA, 0, 10);

        if(in_array($socket, $newSocketArray)) {
            $newSocket = socket_accept($socket);
            $clentSocketarray[] = $newSocket;
            $header = socket_read($newSocket, 1024);
            $chat->sendHeaders($header, $newSocket, "EOPMS/messages", PORT);
            socket_getpeername($newSocket, $client_ip_address);
            $connectionACK = $chat->newConnectionACK($client_ip_address);
            $chat->send($connectionACK, $clentSocketarray);

            $newSocketArrayIndex = array_search($socket, $newSocketArray);
            unset($newSocketArray[$newSocketArrayIndex]);

        }

        foreach($newSocketArray as $newSocketArrayResource) {

            //1
            while(socket_recv($newSocketArrayResource, $socketData, 1024, 0) >= 1) {
                $socketMessage = $chat->unseal($socketData);
                $messageObj = json_decode($socketMessage);
                if ($messageObj->chat_sender != null) {
                    $chatMessage = $chat->createChatMessage($messageObj->chat_sender, $messageObj->chat_message);
                    $chat->send($chatMessage, $clentSocketarray);
                }
                break 2;
            }

            ///2
            $socketData = @socket_read($newSocketArrayResource, 1024, PHP_NORMAL_READ);
            if ($socketData === false) {
                socket_getpeername($newSocketArrayResource, $client_ip_address);
                $connectionACK = $chat->newDisconnectedACK($client_ip_address);
                $chat->send($connectionACK, $clentSocketarray);
                $newSocketArrayIndex = array_search($newSocketArrayResource, $clentSocketarray);
                unset($clentSocketarray[$newSocketArrayIndex]);
            }

        }

    }

    socket_close($socket);

?>
```

chat.php

```
<?php

    class Chat
    {
        public function sendHeaders($headersText, $newSocket, $host, $port) {
            $headers = array();
            $tmpLine = preg_split("/\r\n/", $headersText);

            foreach($tmpLine as $line) {
                $line = rtrim($line);
                if(preg_match("/\A(\S+): (.*)\z/", $line, $matches)) {
                    $headers[$matches[1]] = $matches[2];
                }
            }

            $key = $headers["Sec-WebSocket-Key"];
            $sKey = base64_encode(pack("H*", sha1($key."258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11")));

            $strHeader = "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols \r\n".
                "Upgrade: websocket\r\n".
                "Connection: Upgrade\r\n".
                "WebSocket-Origin: $host\r\n".
                "WebSocket-Location: ws://$host:$port/messages/server.php\r\n".
                "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: $sKey\r\n\r\n";

            socket_write($newSocket, $strHeader, strlen($strHeader));
        }

        public function seal($socketData) {
            $b1 = 0x81;
            $length = strlen($socketData);
            $header = "";
            if ($length <= 125) {
                $header = pack("CC", $b1, $length);
            } elseif ($length > 125 && $length < 65536) {
                $header = pack("CCn", $b1, 126, $length);
            } elseif ($length > 65536) {
                $header = pack("CCNN", $b1, 127, $length);
            }
            return $header.$socketData;
        }

        public function unseal($socketData) {
            $length = ord($socketData[1]) & 127;
            if ($length == 126) {
                $mask = substr($socketData, 4, 4);
                $data = substr($socketData, 8);
            } elseif ($length == 127) {
                $mask = substr($socketData, 10, 4);
                $data = substr($socketData, 14);
            } else {
                $mask = substr($socketData, 2, 4);
                $data = substr($socketData, 6);
            }

            $socketStr = "";
            for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($data); ++$i) {
                $socketStr .= $data[$i] ^ $mask[$i%4];
            }

            return $socketStr;
        }

        public function send($message, $clentSocketArray) {
            $messageLength = strlen($message);
            foreach ($clentSocketArray as $clentSocket) {
                @socket_write($clentSocket, $message, $messageLength);
            }
            return true;
        }

        public function createChatMessage($sender, $messageStr) {
            $messageArray = array('type' => "chat-box", 'sender' => $sender, 'message' => $messageStr);
            return $this->seal(json_encode($messageArray));
        }

        public function newConnectionACK($client_ip_address) {
            $messageArray = array("type" => "connected", "message" => $client_ip_address);
            return $this->seal(json_encode($messageArray));
        }

        public function newDisconnectedACK($client_ip_address) {
            $messageArray = array("type" => "disconnected", "message" => $client_ip_address);
            return $this->seal(json_encode($messageArray));
        }

    }
?>
```

P.S. На вирутальном хостинге, хотя дежурный скрипт принудительно закрывался (почему я и перешёл на VDS), но чат работал. В связи с этим я предполагаю, что здесь просто где-то неправильно прописан путь.

Comment: @Mike, вы правы, это очепятка, я исправил. Но это всё равно не привело к работе чата. Видимо ошибка ещё в чём-то другом

Comment: если php установлен где то не по стандартным путям доступа cron может его не находить. стоит указывать полный путь к php. А вообще надо смотреть системные логи куда крон пишет что он делает. так же посмотреть настройки крона на предмет того куда он девает информацию об ошибках. потому что гадать на кофейной гуще, что может быть не так бесполезно. нужна информация и в системе она есть, надо только ее найти. А еще такие вещи через cron не совсем правильно делать, лучше сделать сервис через какой нибудь systemd или что там у вас в дистрибутиве вместо него

Comment: а для начала просто из консоли запустить эту php и посмотреть работает ли оно

Comment: @Mike Консоль пишет:
PHP Warning: socket_bind(): unable to bind address [98]: Address already in use in /home/admin/web/cy84161.tw1.ru/public_html/messages/server.php on line 9

Comment: значит порт уже чем то занят, например ваш скрипт уже работает. А снаружи порт например закрыт фаерволом у вас же на машине или у вашего хостера. с помощью `ps ax` можете посмотреть все процессы и посмотреть есть ли там ваш скрипт, но скорее всего есть и надо смотреть почему нельзя подключиться

Comment: @Mike но перед тем как я запустил скрипт через консоль, я саспендил его в Cron'е

Comment: Если вы уберете скрипт из крона то никто убивать уже запущенный не будет

Comment: но если скрипт вдруг не запущен значит этот порт занят чем то другим

Comment: @Mike да Вы правы, скрипт идёт. Но socket всё равно выдаёт ошибку, несмотря на то, что скрипт запущен

Comment: @Mike поменял номер порта, теперь "unable" не возникает, но сокет всё равно не соединяется и даёт ошибку

Comment: у вас скорее всего все порты закрыты фаерволом.

Comment: @Mike ни на моем компьютере, ни на хостинге нет ограничений для портов

Comment: @Mike я пробовал запустить файл server.php из консоли, маркировал внутри командами echo, он запускается и текст, который несут echo отображается в консоли. А вот условие {if(in_array($socket, $newSocketArray))} ни разу не выполняется. Поэтому уверен, что ошибка в строке {var socket = new WebSocket("ws://cy84161.tw1.ru:8070/messages/server.php");}, неправильно написан адрес

Comment: @Mike в консоли браузера выходит ошибка

WebSocket connection to 'ws://eopms.tk:4567/messages/server.php' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT